# How to I add an image from a function into an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new to programming so please bear with me.
I want to add an image from my Image called imageCam 
The problem is I do not know how to remove it from the function

I tried this:

```
let camImages : [UIImage] = [imagePickerController.image]
```

The error I get is this:

> Value of type '(CamViewController) -> (UIImagePickerController,
>   [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) -> ()' has no member 'image'

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
    imageCam.image = image

    //  var discover = MainViewController()

    //  discover.stuffImages[IndexPath.row]

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any ideas? I would like to make an array that would keep adding images the user takes.

Comment: Where did you put that `let camImages : [UIImage] = [imagePickerController.image]` line?

Comment: after the code that I added

Comment: First declare your view controller array instance property as variable (not constant) `var camImages : [UIImage] = []` and inside your didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo `camImages.append(image)`. Btw I don't recommend creating an array of images (it will keep them all together in memory until it crashes your app out of memory).